# auto-login in chrome using selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome

i would like to use vba to access a web site and perform other operation once logged in, but i have problem with log in, using this code

```
Dim obj As New WebDriver
Dim Keys As New Keys


obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.Get "https://a14onlinetrackers.azurewebsites.net/trackers/trackerView/1?i=1"


 obj.FindElementByName("loginfmt").SendKeys Keys.Control & "t"

obj.FindElementByName("loginfmt").SendKeys ("xxxx@yyy.com")
obj.FindElementById("idSIButton9").Click
obj.FindElementByName("passwd").SendKeys ("xxxx")
obj.FindElementById("idSIButton9").Click
```

after auto-typing the password i have an error on the submit button.

Can you help?

after login in what would be the code to open a new tab on the same browser?

Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to login?

Comment: I don't get an error, it just type the password but it doesn't click the button to submit it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following codes to log in with VBA, and it works.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim obj As New WebDriver  
    
    With obj
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1594461347&rver=7.0.6738.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Fauth%2Fcomplete-signin%3Fru%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.microsoft.com%252F%253Frefd%253Dlogin.live.com%2526ru%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Faccount.microsoft.com%25252F%25253Frefd%25253Dlogin.live.com&lc=1033&id=292666&lw=1&fl=easi2"
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='form-control ltr_override']").SendKeys ("Your Account")
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='idSIButton9']").Click
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='form-control']").SendKeys ("Your Password")
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='idSIButton9']").Click                 
    End With

    obj.Wait (60000)

End Sub
```

@Fabio Giallombardo, please let me know if this works for you or not. :)