Automating website data extraction with Input texts and submit button using Excel VBA code
I need to automate data extraction process from the website "nepsealpha.com/nepse-data", by providing input values for start date, end date and stock symbol automatically(stock symbols may need to be defined as list in another excel sheet if required). I do not see the element ID or Name in the code after I click inspect tab in website, which is restricting me from providing Input values and click submit button to extract the results and save to the excel file. I would prefer one time five years historical data extracted for all the stocks in one excel sheet and then one excel sheet to be extracted every day for all stock indices available in the input list.
Sample start Code below needs code additions as mentioned:
    Sub SeleniumTest()
       Set mybrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
       mybrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://www.google.com"
      'mybrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://www.nepsealpha.com/nepse-data"
       mybrowser.Get ("/")

       mybrowser.FindElementById("APjFqb").SendKeys "madhu"
       mybrowser.Wait (100)
       mybrowser.FindElementByName("btnK").Click
   End Sub

It would be better if I could get the data extraction process automation code in Excel vba along with a looping process to go through each stock symbol for a start date/end date combination provided(one for all historical 5 years data and one for each day data afterwards).

Useful  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364903/auto-login-in-chrome-using-selenium-vba?rq=3

I could not find the element id or name in the website inspect of the mentioned site, moreover i need to input values and click button and then save the extracted result too.

Are you logging in as user "madhu"? If so it is difficult to reproduce for anybody who could help you.

Here is the "Full Xpath" for the Daily button obtained from the Inspect menu.  /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/button Use it with FindElementByXpath

Find Element by Xpath example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298896/selenium-how-to-use-findelementbyxpath-to-identify-the-element

no madhu is just sample text passed to check what value is returned

could you please help me by providing sample code for the mentioned task
